# Bat inbetween roof boards - seal?

Tags: roof, gap, seal

The gaps in the shingled roof over rough-hewn planks of my sunroom/screened-in room have increased over the years. And now new to that space is a bat or bats. The ceiling beams are visible and goes into a peak at the top, but also out to a peak outside the screening. Can I seal the space between (at least) the two top beams where the bat is obviously letting itself live in luxury?

[image]

I still want it to look "nice". Sealant ideas? Other possibilities?

Comment: Looking "nice" is a matter of opinion (one man's nice castle is another man's garbage heap...) so you'll have to be the one who decides that - we can't help you there.

Comment: Where do you live? In many places it's illegal to prevent bats from roosting. Once they've chosen your home, you have to entice them out by building something nearby which they prefer, you cannot force them out.

Answer (score 0):

You can find matching 1x1 board as trim and cover the edge between rafter and the boards. Almost like a crown moulding

Comment: Good excuse to buy a router and bits to make the 1x1 look nice.